# What is wrong with this SQL WHILE LOOP?

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, sql-server-2014

This nested while loop is only successfully executing the lowest level loop. It refuses to add 1 to @wKey even though I tell it to SET @wKey = @wKey + 1.... What am I doing wrong here? Does SQL not allow nested loops?

```
DECLARE @fMinKey INT;
DECLARE @fMaxKey INT;
DECLARE @wMaxKey INT;
DECLARE @wKey INT;
DECLARE @wDate date;
DECLARE @fcStart DATE;

SET @fMinKey = (select min([fcKey]) from dbo.fact_Fc);

SET @fMaxKey = (select max([fcKey]) from dw.fact_Fc);

SET @wMaxKey = (select max([WellKey]) from dw.fact_Fc);

SET @wKey = 1;

SET @wDate = 
(select min([fapDate]) from dbo.dim_W where [Key] = @wKey);


SET @fcStart = 
(select min([Date]) from dw.fact_Fc where [wKey] = @wKey);


WHILE (@fMinKey <= @fMaxKey)
BEGIN

    WHILE (@wKey <= @wMaxKey)
    BEGIN
            WHILE (@wDate < @fcStart)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dw.fact_FcTemp2 ([wKey], [Date], [pAmount], [fcKey], [AddedDate])
                VALUES (@wKey, @wDate, 0, @fMinKey, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                SET @wDate = dateadd(DAY, 1, @wDate)
            END 
            SET @wKey = @wKey + 1

    END

    SET @fMinKey = @fMinKey + 1
END
```

The resulting table is only showing [wKey] = 1, but it should have rows for multiple different wKeys

Comment: because it's nested. The SET comes after the END of the first WHILE loop. In other words, after the first WHILE loop is completed, then I want to change the @wKey and restart the original loop all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once when @wDate reach @fcStart looks like you never reset @wDate to initial state
So next loop run again

You need some how to reset @wDate for next loop

Also having 3 loops perhaps is miss of design, sql performances does not like loops at all. 
Can you show us data structure and needed result maybe tehe is way to constuct sql whitout 3 nested loops